# Find MAX with JOIN where Field also shows up in another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables: Master, Paper and iCodes. For a certain set of Master.Ref's, I need to find Max(Paper.Date), where the Paper.Code is also in the iCodes table (i.e., Paper.Code is a type of iCode). Master is joined to Paper by the File field.

EDIT:
I only need the Max(Paper.Date) its corresponding Code; I do not need all of the Codes.

I wrote the following but it is very slow. I have a few hundred ref #'s to look for. What is a better way to do this?

```
SELECT Master.Ref,
       Paper.Code,
   mp.MaxDate
FROM ( SELECT p.File ,
              MAX(p.Date) AS MaxDate ,
       FROM Paper       AS p
       LEFT JOIN Master AS m ON p.File = m.File
       WHERE m.Ref IN ('ref1', 'ref2', 'ref3', 'ref4', 'ref5', 'ref6'... )
         AND p.Code IN ( SELECT DISTINCT i.iCode
                         FROM iCodes AS i
                       )
       GROUP BY p.File
     ) AS mp
LEFT JOIN Master ON mp.File     = Master.File
LEFT JOIN Paper  ON Master.File = Paper.File
                AND mp.MaxDate  = Paper.Date
WHERE Paper.Code IN ( SELECT DISTINCT iCodes.iCode
                      FROM iCodes
                    )
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, a subset example from your query would be getting 3 rows for 'Ref3' - Code 'X1' @ Date 1/1/13, Code 'X2' @ Date 2/1/13 and Code 'X3' @ Date 6/1/2013. All of these codes are in fact iCodes and I am getting the most recent date each code was used, but for the 'Ref3' results row, I would only need to see Code 'X3' @ 6/1/13 since it is the most recent date of all the iCodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT m.Ref, p.Code, max(p.date)
FROM Master m LEFT JOIN
     Paper
     ON m.File = p.File
WHERE p.Code IN (SELECT DISTINCT iCodes.iCode FROM iCodes) and
      m.Ref IN ('ref1','ref2','ref3','ref4','ref5','ref6'...)
GROUP BY m.Ref, p.Code;
```

EDIT:

To get the code on the max date, then use window functions:

```
select ref, code, date
from (SELECT m.Ref, p.Code, p.date
             row_number() over (partition by m.Ref order by p.date desc) as seqnum
      FROM Master m LEFT JOIN
           Paper
           ON m.File = p.File
      WHERE p.Code IN (SELECT DISTINCT iCodes.iCode FROM iCodes) and
            m.Ref IN ('ref1','ref2','ref3','ref4','ref5','ref6'...)
     ) mp
where seqnum = 1;
```

The function `row_number()` assigns a sequential number starting at 1 to a group of rows.  The groups are defined by the `partition by` clause, so in this case everything with the same `m.Ref` value would be in a single group.  Within the group, rows are assigned the number based on the `order by` clause.  So, the one with the biggest date gets the value of 1.  That is the row you want.

Comment: I think changing that IN to EXISTS clause will yield some better performance

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, this gives me the Max(Date) of each Paper.Code which is also an iCode. However, I need only the Max(Date) of those results and the corresponding code. I do not need all the codes. I will edit my question to specify this. Thanks.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, this query ran in about half the time, which is excellent! The only problem I am seeing is that if 2 codes were run on the same date, and that is the max date, it will only pick up one of those codes. Is there anyway to remedy this?

Comment: @nethy . . . Yes.  Change `row_number()` to either `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, using RANK worked perfectly. It caught an incorrect record from my original query, runs much faster and is easier to read. TY for introducing me to Rank and Partition!

Comment: @SurendraNathGM, I incorporated EXISTS into the query, which sped it up by a couple of seconds. I can see this being faster than IN() for much bigger queries.